# Как настроить иерархическое отображение в eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Есть вот такая структура пакетов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. имеется пакет `graphics`, а все остальные это его подпакеты. Но отображаются они как независимые пакеты. Можно как то настроить что бы они отображались как бы внутри пакета `graphics`? Так, как все пакеты отображаются относительно папки src.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package Explorer / View Menu / Package Presentation / Hierarchical